# Comparing two arrays. What's the smart way to handle the conditions?

Tags: java, arrays, logical-operators

I want to compute with 2 arrays of 2 values, and I have 5 formulas for 5 different conditions.

For example, the arrays:

```
Array 1: [15, 17]
Array 2: [15, 16]
```

Then there are 5 conditions:

```
AB AC - condition 1
AB AB - condition 2
AB AA - condition 3
AA AC - condition 4
AA AA - condition 5
```

They always have at least 1 same value. If they only have 1 same value, such as the example above, [15,17] and [15,16] where 15(or A) exists in both but 17(can be B or C) and 16(can be B or C) are different, this is the first condition. If they are identical, and each array has 2 different values, such as [15,16] and [15,16], this would be the second condition.

What's a smart way to do this? I'm thinking of using if...

```
if (condition 1){
   formula 1
}else if(condition 2){
   formula 2
}else if(condition 3){
   formula 3
}else if(condition 4){
   formula 4
}else if(condition 5){
   formula 5
}
```

But this looks really hideous and I'm not confident to write the conditions properly with this.

Comment: are you just comparing to check if both arrays are equal?

Comment: I would simply use a `Map<Predicate<T[]>, Comparator<T>>`. That allow you to iterate each predicate, and for the one that return true, get the comparator defined (using a `Stream`, you get your "formula" in one statement).

Comment: With good unit tests correctness shouldn’t be a problem. Then just go ahead and write the conditions the way you find most natural.

Comment: Try Vavr and "matching". Here is small introduction https://www.baeldung.com/vavr-pattern-matching and here something more about your cases: https://blog.softwaremill.com/be-functional-with-java-get-rid-of-if-else-null-checks-with-vavrs-option-c3d3de7a5c1d

Comment: Nice questions btw. And welcome to upvote levels ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as I said in a comment, write good unit tests for all cases. These should assure you of the correctness of whatever solution you end up coding. I and many would prefer to write the unit tests *before* the actual code (search for TDD if this sounds strange and you want to learn more).

Second, my style would use nested if/else statements (pseudocode):

```
    if (arr1[0] != arr2[0]) {
        throw some exception;
    }

    if (arr1[0] == arr1[1]) { // we now know arr1[0] == arr2[0] == arr1[1]
        if (arr2[0] == arr2[1]) { // all equal
            assert arr1[1] == arr2[1];
            // condition 5
        } else {
            // condition 4
        }
    } else { // arr1[0] != arr1[1]
        if (arr2[0] == arr2[1]) { // arr1[0] == arr2[0] == arr2[1]
            // condition 3
        } else {
            if (arr1[1] == arr2[1]) {
                // condition 2
            } else {
                // condition 1
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this is true, it's much simpler than I thought it would be. Thanks, I'll test it out.

Comment: There’s probably a slip somewhere, but the basic idea is sound.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I do not see any way to get rid of those tests. You can hide them between a factory and/or use a `Map<Predicate, BiConsumer>` (where `BiConsumer` is your formula). But in one way or the other you will have those 5 conditions.

The main point to have clean code is to name either your conditions or predicates correctly.